# How to count all values in one key of a pyspark RDD?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

In a pyspark RDD, 'predicted_values' is the key for the results of a logistic regression. Obviously, 'predicted_values' holds only 0 and 1.

I want to count the number of 0's and 1's in the output field.

I try:

```
Counter(rdd.groupByKey()['predicted_value'])
```

which gives

```
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not subscriptable
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [`countByValue()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#countByValue):

```python
sorted(rdd.map(lambda x: x['predicted_value']).countByValue().items())
#[(0, 580), (1, 420)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this can be done by (using the Counter class from `collection`):

```
>>> Counter([i['predicted_value'] for i in rdd.collect()]

Counter({0: 580, 1: 420})
```

Comment: Generally, you'll want to avoid `collect` as that will bring all of the data to the driver. At that point, you'll be using pure python and will not get the benefits of Spark/distributed computing